# How to move the file pointer to next character through "ifstream" without "getting" any character, just like "fseek" does?

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

**seekg** uses **ios** as the second argument, and **ios** can be set to *end* or *beg* or some other values as shown here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/

I just want the pointer to move to the next character, how is that to be accomplished through **ifstream**?

**EDIT**
Well, the problem is that I want a function in **ifstream** similar to **fseek**, which moves the pointer without reading anything.

Comment: how about simply doing a dummy read of current character?

Comment: actually, I am using `getline` function to get the line uptill '\n' character. Now I want to read "from" the just read '\n' to the next '\n'.

Comment: I don't quite understand what's there problem with that. Could you post an example file of the kind you want to read from, and what you actually want to get from it?

Comment: getline() consumes '\n'. After one getline() you're immediately ready to call another, no repositioning needed.

Comment: But still, isn't there any function equivalent to fseek in ifstream?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ifstream fin(...);
// ...

fin.get(); // <--- move one character
// or
fin.ignore(); // <--- move one character
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I use the "ignore" will that effect the `getline` function which I want to use with pointer set to the next character? I mean will the ignored character be read by the `getline` then?

Comment: I feared that! I want it to be read by the `getline`. I just want the pointer to be moved without "getting" anything.

Comment: @Anisha: but that's impossible, getting *is* reading from the current position of the pointer! Maybe you should post what your problem *is* and ask for a proper solution.

Comment: @Anisha Kaul: When you move the pointer with seek or get or ignore you are moving the position of the pointer from which the next read will take place. You are in affect reading the next character (or moving over it) to set the position from which a read will take place. Explain the real problem. Your edit is explaining the solution you want to a problem that we don't understand. If you explain the real problem, what problem are you trying to solve that requires you to move forward one character, maybe we can suggest a better solution. i.e. we need more context.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Its called [seekg()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/) as you seem to already know?

```
std::ifstream is("plop.txt" );

// Do Stuff

is.seekg (1, std::ios::cur);  // Move 1 character forward from the current position.
```

Note this is the same as:

```
is.get();

// or 

is.ignore();
```

Answer (score 4):

Read the docs for [`seekg`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/) and use `ios_base::cur` as indicated there.

Comment: Thanks again, but the doc says `current position within sequence`. And how is that going to move the pointer? I couldn't get the point.

Comment: The docs says "current position in the stream buffer". With an offset of one and `::cur`, you'll move one byte forward.

Comment: Let me try that and see what happens.

Comment: Is there something else to this? I've used `std::ostream &s` to do `s.seekp(-2, std::ios_base::cur);` in order to overwrite the last two chars by immediately doing `s << ">]";`, but the last 2 chars that should be overwritten (1 comma + 1 space) are still there and not overwritten; the `">]"` chars do not show up in the stream..

Answer (score 0):

I guess [peek()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/peek/) and [unget()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/unget/) could be useful too.

Use peek() to peek next character so that getline will work as you have wanted.

Use unget to put the character back to your buffer in case you have used get() method.